# Get (integer[]) array value from the query result of PostgreSQL using libpq library

Tags: c, postgresql, libpq

after executing query I run below functions but don't know how to convert value to c integer array.

how to get integer array from pptRawValue where COLUMN_VALUE_IN_BINARY_FORMAT
when I looked at memory i can see the value are present in pptRawValue but not able to get that values in integer array in c code?

### please help.

```
long lColumnNum = PQfnumber(ptQueryRes, pstrColumnName);
long lFormat = PQfformat(ptQueryRes, lColumnNum);
*pptRawValue = PQgetvalue(ptQueryRes, lRowNum, lColumnNum);
*plValueLength = PQgetlength(ptQueryRes, lRowNum, lColumnNum);
int iarray[];
```

Comment: "`integer`" is not a C data type (though the term is used for a *category* of data types).  Do you mean `int`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Found the way to extract values from received binary array

The received binary array has below format.
I have actually verified it.

This didn't quite agree with what I found but it gave me a starting point.
  Here is what I found and hope experts will correct me if I am wrong:

The first 20 bytes seem to have the following information about the array:

--first 4 bytes    don't know what it is but it is always 1
      This is may be format number as Laurenz Albe mentioned above.
                     Reference:https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol-overview.html#PROTOCOL-FORMAT-CODES
--second 4 bytes    "     "    "    "  " "    "  "   "    0
--third 4 bytes    oid of the datatype in the array
--4th 4 bytes      number of  elements in the array
--5th 4 bytes      dimension of the array

Form here we have the actual data. Each datum is preceeded with a 4 byte 
  integer indicating the number of bytes the next element occupies. Knowing 
  the number of elements one can parse the memory and get access to the 
  elements.

Please fallow the link: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/attachment/13504/arrayAccess.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can either request text mode output, then an `integer[]` would look like `{1,2,42}`, or you can request binary mode, but then you'd have to deal with the internal array representation of the PostgreSQL server.

About binary mode for `integer[]`:

[Integers themselves are represented in network byte order](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol-overview.html#PROTOCOL-FORMAT-CODES), so endianness shouldn't be a problem.

You'll have to read the PostgreSQL source to understand the structure of an `ArrayType`.

Binary more could be a problem if client and server have a different architecture, because the alignment might differ.

Comment: yes but currently I cannot convert it to text as it is requirement but i can use ntohl, ntohs,

Comment: That's no problem (I have expanded the answer). The internal structure of the array is the problem.

Comment: yes I read about internal format however first I am checking if the response in binary format if yes i am going ahead.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: going forward the text option will available to me so it will be more save.
Thanks for alert.